# Fetching additional data from AWS SNS Push Notification

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a problem regarding my SNS Push Notifications. I have the following lambda code:

```
    db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err); // an error occurred
          } 
        else {

        data.Items.forEach(function(record) {

            var receiverID = record.userDeviceToken.S;
            var message = "You have a new invitation to the event";
            var topic = "Friend's invitation";

            var eventText = JSON.stringify(event);
            console.log("Received event:", eventText);
            var sns = new AWS.SNS();
            var params = {
                Message: message, 
                Subject: "Friend's invitation",
                TargetArn: receiverID,
            };

            sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Failed to publish SNS message');
                context.fail(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('SNS message published successfully');
                context.succeed(data);
            }
            });

        });

        //context.succeed(data.Items); // data.Items

      }
  });
};
```

Now my goal is to get the "Subject" or "topic" sometimes, if it is possible. I cannot find it in documentation, and I need it to customize my notification title depending on the push message sent (I have few functions).

When I used sample amazon app I found this cound in Push Listener Service:

```
public static String getMessage(Bundle data) {
        // If a push notification is sent as plain text, then the message appears in "default".
        // Otherwise it's in the "message" for JSON format.
        return data.containsKey("default") ? data.getString("default") : data.getString(
                "message", "");
    }
```

This works, but the "data" itself has the following data:

```
Bundle[{google.sent_time=1480364966070, google.message_id=0:1480364966079787%22269524f9fd7ecd, default=You have a new invitation to the event, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

Therefore, it is just providing some internal data and the "message" itself. I cannot access the topic.
My question is: how to get other variables in the Android code so I can use them further on? Can I add custom variables by myself through data bundle?

I have notifications in JSON format. I just wonder, whether the only way is to put the data I want in JSON format inside the message, and then read the message accordingly, or maybe I can attach the required data from lambda function to the push notification already?